# Is it possible to run a batch file within a JFace wizard with progress monitor?

Tags: java, eclipse, jface

I want to run a batch script from within my JFace wizard, and even I want to show the progress monitor for that within the wizard.

Why I want this because, when I run a batch script within my java code, the control on batch script execution gets lost from java code. That's why I'm thinking whether is it possible to run this within the wizard so that I should have the control.

Reagrds,

Anand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be able to measure the script's progress somehow.
For example, if the script could log its progress to the file, then a thread in your application could read it and pass to the progress monitor (by calling IProgressMonitor#worked(valueFromFile))